# Posting to friends' wall with Graph API via 'feed' connection failing since Feb 6th 2013

Tags: facebook-graph-api, stream, publishing

My app started failing to post items on friends' feeds.
I am getting this error:

```
Facebook request error: The operation couldn’t be completed.
(facebookErrDomain error 10000.), details: Error Domain=facebookErrDomain Code=10000 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (facebookErrDomain error 10000.)" UserInfo=0xa26e990 {error={
    code = 200;
    message = "(#200) Feed story publishing to other users is disabled for this application";
    type = OAuthException;
}}
```

I didn't change anything in the app. Maybe it is related with Facebook upgrade?
These are the permissions that I connect to Facebook with:

```
[appDelegate.facebook authorize:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_stream", @"friends_birthday", nil]];
```

Comment: Yes, this was announced months ago and took effect on Feb 6th - https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/completed-changes/

Comment: But was is the problem? I cannot post on a friend feed anymore? Are you sure Facebook blocked that?

Comment: How can I enable my App for publishing stories on other users?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, this was [announced](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/migrations/completed-changes#feb_2013) months ago and took effect on Feb 6th 2013:

> **Removing ability to post to friends walls via Graph API** 
>   We will remove the ability to post to a user's friends' walls via the Graph API. Specifically, posts against [user_id]/feed where [user_id] is different from the session user, or stream.publish calls where the `target_id` user is different from the session user, will fail. If you want to allow people to post to their friends' timelines, invoke the [feed dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/). Stories that include friends via [user mentions tagging](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/mention_tagging/) or [action tagging](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/#taggingpeople/) will show up on the friend’s timeline (assuming the friend approves the tag). For more info, see [this blog post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/10/10/growing-quality-apps-with-open-graph/).

The workaround is to use the [Feed Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) which allows users to post the same content, but choose the user they want to post it to.

Comment: This is so sad... :(  Took me quite a while to make this feed work properly back then... Now I will have to make it again...

Comment: Can you please help me **[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15740168/facing-issue-while-trying-to-send-the-reply-to-facebook-post-in-mvc3)** ?

Comment: @Igy is it possible to post something via the feed dialog to multiple users, instead of just one?

Comment: No; the send dialog supports choosing multiple recipients but the feed dialog allows one friend only

Comment: Working correctly in iphone and ipad but facing this issue when try to publish on friend,s wall using android.