# (#200) Feed story publishing to other users is disabled for this application

Tags: fbconnect

we are sending invitation via facebook graph api. and our code is working fine before some days but now i always fount error (#200) Feed story publishing to other users is disabled for this application in our Application.

please suggested me anybody what to do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Posting to friends' wall with Graph API via 'feed' connection failing since Feb 6th 2013](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14792062/posting-to-friends-wall-with-graph-api-via-feed-connection-failing-since-feb)

Answer (score 2):

Facebook removed this on Feb 6th.

See similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14792062/posting-to-friends-wall-with-graph-api-via-feed-connection-failing-since-feb) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14056046/feed-story-publishing-to-other-users-is-disabled-for-this-application).