# How to post message to friend's Facebook wall

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

First I tried to post message to my id which successfully sent to my wall. Now I am trying to post a message to a particular friend's Facebook wall using Python as shown in my code below:

```
friends = graph.get_object("me/friends")
friends_id = friends['data'][0]['id']
graph.put_object(friends_id,"feed",message="For testing purpose sent from terminal")
```

When I tried to post the message to my friend I am getting the errorL

```
"facebook.GraphAPIError: (#200) Feed story publishing to other users is disabled for this application"
```

I tried to fix the error, but I got the solution like "we are not able to post friend's feed".

Comment: yes i don't know where i have to enabled??? can u plz tell me where i have to enabled it??

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Facebook [removed the functionality](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/migrations/completed-changes) for posting to other people's walls using this particular API on October 2th 2013.

An alternative method for your use-case would be to use the [send dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog/v2.0).

Although, this sends a message to the user, posting to the wall of a friend is not possible at all.

Please see these questions where this has been discussed previously (on other tags):

1. [Feed story publishing to other users is disabled for this application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14056046/feed-story-publishing-to-other-users-is-disabled-for-this-application)
2. [Posting to friends' wall with Graph API via 'feed' connection failing since Feb 6th 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14792062/posting-to-friends-wall-with-graph-api-via-feed-connection-failing-since-feb)

Comment: actually, you cannot post anything on the wall of a friend with the feed dialog. you would need to use the send dialog.

Comment: @luschn feel free to edit my community wiki if you know more details :) I've made it a CW intentionally as all I've not got much experience with it.

Comment: ah, didn´t know i could do that :)

Comment: we can post message on the others facebook wall using send dialog in python right??

Comment: @PythonTeam you should check the documentation but it looks like it.

Comment: python? no, in javascript, with the javascript sdk. well, you cannot post something on their wall, you can send them a message. posting something on the wall of a friend is not possible at all with the API, luckily. i have edited the answer a bit.

Comment: btw, the date was wrong too, it was removed in october 2013: "Removing the ability to post to friends' timelines via API"